# Keycloak oidc token

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid-connect

I have a user with all permissions. I request a token(without browser auth, by grant_type=password) and get an access_token, which can be used to view events. I successfully login through oidc and get an acces_token, but I can't use this token to view events(401 unauthorized).
Here is code to get token without browser login:

```py
import requests

payload = {
        "client_id": "lox",
        "client_secret": "394bcd36-b576-42e2-80ae-d349eef941b9",
        "grant_type": "password",
        "username": "a",
        "password": "a",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    }
http = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/token"
a = requests.post(http, data=payload)
a = a.json()
print(a['access_token'])

#test access_token
http2 = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/admin/realms/demo/events'
header = {
    'Authorization': "Bearer " + a['access_token']
}
b = requests.request("GET", http2, headers=header)
b = b.json()
```

By this access_token i can see/manage users/events.
This is oidc login code:

```py
client_id = 'lox'
client_secret = '394bcd36-b576-42e2-80ae-d349eef941b9'
redirect_uri = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
scope = 'openid email profile'

oauth = OAuth2Session(client_id, redirect_uri=redirect_uri, scope=scope)

authorization_url, state = oauth.authorization_url(
    'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/auth')

print(authorization_url)
authorization_response = input()
token = oauth.fetch_token(
    'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/token',
    authorization_response=authorization_response,
    client_secret=client_secret)
r = oauth.get('http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo')
r = oauth.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/admin/realms/demo/events')
```

I successfully get user-info(that's mean the token is valid), but when I'm trying to view events I get 401 error.

Comment: Please post more details of what the access token contains and how you configured your API